# node.js and websocket: is it possible to run into race condition?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am new to node.js and websockets.

Let's take this snippet of code that makes use of websocket in node js:

```
var myMap = new Map();
//some code here
socket.on('next', function(id) {    
    User.findById(id, function (err, entry) {
        // some code here
        entry.save(function (err){
            myMap.delete(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Can this code run into race condition with respect to the shared variable myMap? User is a mongoose based object.

I know that javascript and node.js are single threaded. However, the callback where myMap is accessed (myMap.delete(id)) confuses me.

Comment: The Node is single thread, so `myMap` is changed consistently. On the other hand callback `myMap.delete` can be called for already deleted item by concurrent request.